# wrong answer in kadanes algorithm

Tags: c++

> kadane's algorithm implementation 
>   input = (t=1;n=3;arr={-1,4,5}) gives output 8 but expected output was 9.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int Max( int *arr, int n){
  int currmax = arr[0];
  int globalmax = arr[0];
  for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    currmax= max(currmax, currmax + arr[i]);
    if(currmax > globalmax)
      globalmax = currmax;
  }
  return globalmax;
}

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while(t--){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> arr[i];
      cout << Max(arr, n) << " ";
  }
}
```

Comment: OT: `int n; cin >> n; int arr[n];` makes `arr` an variable length array. If your compiler does not complain about it - I do. It's optional part of the C11 standard but not in C++. The proper alternative is e.g. `std::vector`.

Comment: ref second last solution in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/ also use debugger to see where you going wrong.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `currmax= max(currmax, currmax+arr[i])` to  `currmax= max(arr[i], currmax+arr[i])` as to compare current value with array value.

In you case -1, 4, 5
Value of currmax will be updated as below:
1. currmax = -1, currmax+arr[1] = 3 (compare btw(4,3))
2. currmax= 4 , currmax+arr[2] = 9 (compare btw(5,9))
3. currmax = 9
Code Below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int Max( int *arr, int n){

    int currmax=arr[0];
    int globalmax=arr[0];

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
             currmax= max(arr[i], currmax+arr[i]); // your code line was wrong  here  check and try
             if(currmax>globalmax) 
                    globalmax=currmax;
    }
    return globalmax;

}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>arr[i];
        cout<<Max(arr,n)<<" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the correct Answer for Maximum SubArray (Kadane's Theorem)

C# Solution:

```
    public int MaxSubArray(int[] nums) {
    int maxSum = nums[0];
    int currSum = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++){
        
        currSum = currSum + nums[i];
          
        if(maxSum < currSum){
            maxSum = currSum;
        } 
        
        if(currSum < 0){
            currSum = 0;
        }    
    }
    
    return maxSum;
}
```

[image]

```
enter code here
```